# Running lapply with a 2 argument table function

Tags: r

I have this formula which works exactly as I want it but I need to lapply it to each variable in the dataset.

```
prop.table(table(df$value, df$factorvar), 2)
```

Previously, when I didn't have to crosstab by factor I was able to use this function as part of an lapply like this:

```
basic.calc <- function(x){Props = prop.table(table(x))}

lapply(df, basic.calc)
```

I have yet to figure out how to feed the second argument into this. Any idea on how to use this or better yet a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sample data with desired output would be helpful.

Comment: I'm really unclear what you are trying to do ... you have df  in your lappy, does that refer to a dataframe? Because the function sure looks like it is looking for a single variable, e.g. `prop.table(table(mtcars$carb))` not `prop.table(table(mtcars))`. But yet you say your are getting what you want   with that?

Answer (score 1):

May be this is what you are looking for (using mtcars data):

```
poss.comb<-combn(names(mtcars),2) # 55 possible combination
a1<-my[seq(1,length(my),2)]
a2<-my[seq(2,length(my),2)]
basic.calc <- function(x,y){prop.table(table(mtcars[,x],mtcars[,y]),2)}
final<-mapply(basic.calc,a1,a2) #list 
#For example if you want to extract for mpg and cyl, you can use `final[[1]]`
```